# Customize quarter month range

Tags: sas

I used `YYQ5.` to create a new variable based on dates in `MMDDYY10.` format. The problem is is that I have the date range for my annual quarters to be different than the SAS annual quarter period.

I originally had something like:

```
data recog_flag;
    set recog;
    if '01nov2010'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '31jan2011'd then quart = 1;
    else if '01feb2011'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '30apr2011'd  then quart = 2;
    else if '01may2011'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '31jun2011'd  then quart = 3;
    else if '01aug2011'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '31oct2011'd  then quart = 4;
    else if '01nov2011'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '31jan2012'd  then quart = 5;
    else if '01feb2012'd <= FINAL_DECISION <= '30apr2012'd  then quart = 6;
    run;
```

EDIT: updated date labels.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe, there is a typo in your last ELSE IF: last date should be 04/30/12 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can use INTCK() function with shifted interval:

```
data have;
    do date='01Nov2010'd to '30Apr2012'd;
        output;
    end;
    format date MMDDYY10.;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    quart=intck('qtr.2','01Nov2010'd,date)+1;
run;
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It eliminated the other variables. Do I need to specify 'retain' or something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by other variables? In my code I'm creating sample input dataset (HAVE) where there's only one variable - `date`. And then I add variable `quart` in the next data step. Did you change in my code datasets' and variables' names to your real ones?

Answer (score 1):

I would define a function in FCMP to calculate your quarter value.  Then create a new format based on that function (or just use the function in the data step).

```
options cmplib=work.fns;

proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.formats;
function newQtr(date) $;
    new_date = intnx('month',date,2,'sameday');
    qtr = qtr(new_date);
    year = year(new_date);
    qtr = (year-2011)*4+qtr;
    return(put(qtr,4.));
endsub;
run;

proc format;
value nQTR
    other=[newQtr()];
run;

data test;
format x  date9. q nQTR. q2;
do x="01NOV2010"d to "31JAN2012"d by 25;
q=x;
q2 = input(newQTR(x),best.);
output;
end;
run;

proc print data=test(obs=10);
run;
```

Produces:

```
                          Obs            x    q    q2

                             1    01NOV2010    1     1
                             2    26NOV2010    1     1
                             3    21DEC2010    1     1
                             4    15JAN2011    1     1
                             5    09FEB2011    2     2
                             6    06MAR2011    2     2
                             7    31MAR2011    2     2
                             8    25APR2011    2     2
                             9    20MAY2011    3     3
                            10    14JUN2011    3     3
```

Comment: This answer is more useful if you want to retain the entire date variable and just want to apply a format to it; the other answer is easier if you're okay with either a new variable with '1,2,3,4,5,etc' values and/or with dumping the date variable.